# BeautifulSoup parse table data that doesn't load immediately

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download earnings announcement data from https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/MMM/earnings-announcements using beautifulsoup.  When I look at the tables, the table I am interested in (earnings_announcements_earnings_table) shows only "Loading Data…".  However, if I print the entire contents of the soup, I do see the information I am looking for is in there.  I can isolate this data just a "script" element, but that contains a lot of other unwanted info.  How can I select and parse just the specific data I'm looking for, which is the contents of the "earnings_announcements_earnings_table" table, which looks like this:

"    var obj = {
              "earnings_announcements_earnings_table"   : 
             [  [ "10/25/2016", "9/2016", "$2.14", "--", "--", "Before Open" ] ,..."

Here is what I have so far:

```
from urllib import request
from urllib import error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_parse_earnings(symbol):

request_string = "https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/%s/earnings-announcements" % symbol
print(request_string)

try:
    web = request.urlopen(request_string)
except error.HTTPError:
    return

soup = BeautifulSoup(web.read(), 'lxml')
data = soup.find_all("script")[28].string
print(data)
```

Comment: What, specifically, are you attempting to retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to fire up Selenium and make use of its Javascript engine. That's not really simple, and I offer here an alternative solution which is a total hack, but it should work for the pages you are interested in.

Assuming the pages are generated automatically, we observe that the data you want is in (continuing from you program):

```
import json
earnings = json.loads(data.split('var obj =')[1].splitlines()[2])
```

This is leveraging the fact that Javascript objects are JSON, and so we read directly from the source. The result is a list of lists like this one:

```
[['10/25/2016', '9/2016', '.14', '--', '--', 'Before Open'],
 ['7/26/2016',
  '6/2016',
  '.08',
  '.08',
  '<div class=right pos_na showinline>0.00 (0.00%)</div>',
  'Before Open'],
 ['4/26/2016',
  '3/2016',
  '.92',
  '.05',
  '<div class=right pos positive pos_icon showinline up>0.13 (6.77%)</div>',
  'Before Open'],
 ['1/26/2016',
  '12/2015',
  '.62',
  '.80',
  '<div class=right pos positive pos_icon showinline up>0.18 (11.11%)</div>',
  'Before Open'],
 ['10/22/2015',
  '9/2015',
  '.01',
  '.05',
  '<div class=right pos positive pos_icon showinline up>0.04 (1.99%)</div>',
  'Before Open'],
...
]
```

The first element corresponds to the first row of the table, i.e. the header. You just have to clean up the data now.

Answer (score 0):

Without using Selenium but still using json as in the first answer you can dig out the content you need with BS.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib import request
>>> URL='https://www.zacks.com/stock/research/MMM/earnings-announcements'
>>> HTML=request.urlopen(URL).read()
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(HTML)
>>> import json
>>> scripts=soup.findAll('script')
>>> len(scripts)
36

>>> for script in scripts:
...     if script.has_attr('type') and script.attrs['type']=='text/javascript' and script.text.strip().startswith('$(document).ready(function()'):
...         break
```

With this the javascript becomes available as script.text. You would still need to do something mildly clever to extract the lines shown in [Rubik's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448496/rubik) answer. Nothing like impossible though.

Comment: You can pass a regex to find which would avoid the need to iterate over every script tag. `script  = soup.find("script", text='$(document).ready(function()')`